# Layout Rows and Columns to Expand as a percentage of overall screen width

Tags: flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and am trying to create a row/column layout that has container areas that I can then populate with specialized widgets but I am struggling to get the appropriate layout.

I have manually hard-coded widths into the columns and containers but I would like to divide the layout into 1/3 2/3 with some padding around the columns

```html
 body: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(height: 20.0, width:100, color: Colors.yellow),
                  Container(height: 220.0, width:100,color: Colors.green),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(height: 200.0,width:100, color: Colors.cyan),
          ]),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child:  Container(width:600,color: Colors.amber),
         
          ),
        
      ]),
```

This produces a layout but it's hard coded, I would like to use a percentage of the current device's screen width.[image]

[image: Actual Flutter Screen based on code example]

Comment: Please use Expanded Widget and give a child as a container this will resolve your issue. Using Expanded you don't have to give height and width manually thanks. Along with Expanded use the flex property to adjust the width

Answer (score 0):

Row and column take the size of their parent if there ain't one then they take the size of the content.
For this you can put a Container in front of row and specify the size of it.
Somewhat Like this
Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
child:Row(
0.75 is for 75%